# How to change locale of boot menu of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

The locale of boot menu can be checked with `bcdedit`, how to change the locale attribute?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  zh-CN
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {82ae1d6d-4c6a-11e7-bbe7-484d7ecdb30c}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {82b54566-4c6a-11e7-bbe7-484d7ecdb30c}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {82ae1d6d-4c6a-11e7-bbe7-484d7ecdb30c}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} locale en-US`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the C:\ system partition was set to en-GB; I tried the command line above and it didn't reset the C:\ partition.  I had to modify it to this: bcdedit /set {current} locale en-US, and then my locale changed on my C:\ partition.  I kept getting the British spelling of Centre every time it appeared in my menus or commands/options, e.g. Network and Settings Centre.